# Importing constans from one JavaScript file to another one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import the constans from one `JS` file to another `JS` file.

Consider the following files:

Constans file (consts.js):

```
const cars = ["honda","mitsubishi","mercedes"];

export { cars };
```

Main javascript file (main.js):

```
import { cars } from './consts.js';

let initNumberOfCars = 0;
let speed = 80;
...
```

But I get the following error on line 1 at `main.js`:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

How should I import the consts from one `js` file to another one?

Comment: What do you use to transpile your code from ES6? Babel?

Comment: it looks like there is no transpiler at all

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work as is. It must be a Babel issue. If you don't have babel you'll need to look into setting it up with Webpack or Parcel for minimal config.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

https://parceljs.org/

https://webpack.js.org/

https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Alright, I just updated it @Bergi I was just leaving it in case he was trying it so if he came back and was confused by why the answer is gone.

Comment: Is there a way to import without Babel?

Comment: @vesii It will only work in browsers that support it. For the ones that don't you need to transpile it or don't use it. Or if you're in NodeJS use `require`.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import